# pandas.to_datetime not converting all rows to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

simple transformation to convert a string date time to datetime in a df not working - please see last column 990 onwards

```
new_df = pd.melt(
    frame=df,
    id_vars={'Date', 'Day'}
)

new_df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='raise')
```

```
           Date  Day       variable   value   new_date
0      1/5/2015  289   Cases_Guinea  2776.0 2015-01-05
1      1/4/2015  288   Cases_Guinea  2775.0 2015-01-04
2      1/3/2015  287   Cases_Guinea  2769.0 2015-01-03
3      1/2/2015  286   Cases_Guinea     NaN 2015-01-02
4    12/31/2014  284   Cases_Guinea  2730.0 2014-12-31
5    12/28/2014  281   Cases_Guinea  2706.0 2014-12-28
6    12/27/2014  280   Cases_Guinea  2695.0 2014-12-27
7    12/24/2014  277   Cases_Guinea  2630.0 2014-12-24
8    12/21/2014  273   Cases_Guinea  2597.0 2014-12-21
9    12/20/2014  272   Cases_Guinea  2571.0 2014-12-20
..          ...  ...            ...     ...        ...
990   12/3/2014  256  Deaths_Guinea     NaN        NaT
991  11/30/2014  253  Deaths_Guinea  1327.0        NaT
992  11/28/2014  251  Deaths_Guinea     NaN        NaT
993  11/23/2014  246  Deaths_Guinea  1260.0        NaT
994  11/22/2014  245  Deaths_Guinea     NaN        NaT
995  11/18/2014  241  Deaths_Guinea  1214.0        NaT
996  11/16/2014  239  Deaths_Guinea  1192.0        NaT
997  11/15/2014  238  Deaths_Guinea     NaN        NaT
```

Comment: please fix your column headers and explain how this fails

Comment: @mozway - it is causing "NaT" for row 990 onwards and not converting to actual dates even though the string formatted dates are legit. Those work if I test them with standard python datetime lib

Comment: Use: `new_df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='raise')`, you kept `df` in place of `new_df`. Voting to close as typo ;)